# Deserializing Json Array to C# List<T>

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I'm new at Json Serialization and Deserialization,

I have

```
class TestClass
{

    public string Name{get;set;}
    public string Age{get;set;}
    public string Height{get;set;}

}
```

and have the following serialization function

```
public void SerializeData()
{

    string jsonData = "{
           {"Name" : "Zeus","Age" : "1825","Height" : "900"},
           {"Name" : "Hera","Age" : "1805","Height" : "200"}
     }";

    var resultList = new List<TestClass>();
    var ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    resultList= serializer.Deserialize(jsonData , TestClass)

}
```

but it doesn't work! keeps throwing "Argument Exception"

Any Help Please?

Comment: please be a bit more explicit about the exception it throws.

Comment: You can check if your json is valid or not from  http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your JSON might be incorrect.

A `List` maps more closely to a JSON array - like:

```
 [
       {"Name" : "Zeus","Age" : "1825","Height" : "900"},
       {"Name" : "Hera","Age" : "1805","Height" : "200"}
 ]
```

If you want to use outer curly braces `{}` then you can serialize to/from a `Dictionary<string, TestClass>` using JSON like:

```
 {
       "Zeus" : {"Name" : "Zeus","Age" : "1825","Height" : "900"},
       "Hera" : {"Name" : "Hera","Age" : "1805","Height" : "200"}
 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

this does not represent an array:

```
string jsonData = "{
           {"Name" : "Zeus","Age" : "1825","Height" : "900"},
           {"Name" : "Hera","Age" : "1805","Height" : "200"}
     }";
```

In order to have an array you should have:

```
string jsonData = "[
           {"Name" : "Zeus","Age" : "1825","Height" : "900"},
           {"Name" : "Hera","Age" : "1805","Height" : "200"}
     ]";
```